# MS SQL Server Management Studio - How to create new schema

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I want to create a new schema in SSMS with the **Schema - New** dialog box but I can't find how.
I know it's supposed to open when I right click on the *Databases/xyz/Security/Schemas* folder in the Object Explorer and select *New Schema...* but all I get is a query to create it.

I just started an edX course called *Developing SQL Databases*, there are no instructions there concerning the SSMS settings, the only instructions say that I should be able to get the **Schema - New** dialog box. I asked there in the discussion but nobody replies, actually there's no activity there whatsoever so probably nobody even knows I asked.
I did google it but the only relevant results I found say the same thing, right-click, New Schema... and the dialog box opens. But it doesn't.

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Expand the database in the Object Explorer, and right-click the Security folder, then select "New" (the Security folder under the database, **NOT** the Security folder under the server).

Comment: That's where I'm trying. The other doesn't even have a Schemas folder.

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: version 13.0.15700.28

Comment: I just noticed that when I installed the update a few days ago, it installed it next to SSMS 16. So I have SSMS 17 installed, version 14.0.17099.0, but there's no difference.

Answer (score 4):

I realize your question is how to do this in SSMS, but the tsql code for this is only five words.

```
create schema MyNewSchema authorization dbo;
```

That seems much simpler to me.

Comment: The OP know the t-sql command [**but all I get is a query to create it.**], he is asking about how to create schema via SSMS.

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader I realize that. That is the first sentence in my answer. Though this may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure you are searching in a right folder.

the security folder is under the database , not under the server.

as next screenshot:-

[image]

**UPDATE:-**

This issue is repeated [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2d5075f7-158d-4264-9697-953a84421615/schemas-folder-not-shown-in-sql-server-management-studio-2014-x64?forum=sqlexpress), and the soluation was the following:-

1. Full uninstall Manual
2. deletion of all MSSQL-folders in
   AppData{Local|Roaming}
3. Reinstall
4. Checking for any updates

and everything is as expected, so try these steps.

Comment: That's where I'm trying. The other doesn't even have a Schemas folder.